# Subsetting POSIXct date and time returns wrong date

Tags: r, posixct

I have the following data frame containing date and time in POSIXct format in time zone UTC:

```
date<-c("2013-12-12","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01")
time<-c("23:00:00","00:00:00","01:00:00","02:00:00")
x<-data.frame(date,time)
x$Date2<-as.POSIXct(paste(x$date, x$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
```

After subsetting the data frame with:

```
x<-subset(x, Date2<="2014-01-01 00:00:00")
```

I am not getting the correct date and time:

```
        date     time               Date2
1 2013-12-12 23:00:00 2013-12-12 23:00:00
```

Should´t I rather get:

```
        date     time               Date2
1 2014-01-01 00:00:00 2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `"2014-01-01 00:00:00"` is a string and you are comparing `POSIXct` class with a character class. Convert it into `POSIXct` and it should work

```
subset(x, Date2 <= as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"))

#        date     time               Date2
#1 2013-12-12 23:00:00 2013-12-12 23:00:00
#2 2014-01-01 00:00:00 2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

Here, both the rows are selected since both of them are less than equal to date-time compared.

Comment: I am just worried that if I merge two data frames based on date and time that the merge will result in errors or does R recognise the previously set time zone as UTC when using `merge`in R?

Comment: And why is the time omitted if I subset with: `x<-subset(x, Date2==as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"))`

Comment: @Matt it should not be a problem until you keep all the values in the same timezone, if they are in different time zone make them consistent and bring them together. Regarding your other question time is not omitted, it is just not displayed. Check `class(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"))`

Answer (score 4):

This is a time zone problem.  When you compare the string to the `POSIXct` value it converts the string `s` below to a POSIXct value relative to the current default time zone of your session.

We see how the answer changes when we change the default time zone for the session:

```
s <- "2000-01-01 00:00:00"

Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT")
as.POSIXct(s, tz = "GMT") == s
## [1] TRUE

Sys.setenv(TZ = "")  # "" will set your TZ to your usual session default
as.POSIXct(s, tz = "GMT") == s
## [1] FALSE
```

Thus you can either explicitly convert your strings to POSIXct specifying the time zone or else you can set your session time zone to the same time zone as your POSIXct objects.

Comment: But when I execute the `paste`command I explicitly specify tz as UTC.

Comment: Right. You are comparing a POSIXct object that has its time zone set explicitly to a string which has its time zone set from the current session default when R coerces it to POSIXct and those two time zones are different.  Set your session time zone to be the same as your explicitly set time zone or explicitly convert the string you are comparing to before the comparison as discussed in my answer.